# IOS Does a chart can be in box form shown in image

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, charts

[image: Image101]

[image: Image102]

[image: Image103]

[image: Image104]

I want a customised chart in form of box shown in above image101. But problem is that if there are 3 options than the chart should be in the form of 3 Options Chart and if there are 2 Options than chart should be in the form of 2 Options shown in image102 depends on the server response. Or please suggest me some third party library to overcome from my situation.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about collection view ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks for reply ya we can but this chart is in the tableviewcell and in that table this chart has to be shown i have added some more screenshots you can check that, that what i want. On tapping that chart it gets opened and on tapping on that black chart it opens on that white one.

Comment: You can put collection view in table cell too,

Comment: But reusing that cell would not get heavy to load because there are images in it also and other information which i have not shown

Comment: If you intend to display complex, custom, unpredictable content, you can't rely on the convenience of reusing cells for performance.

Comment: @Stonz2 Ya thats correct. Okay so i am keeping aside for reusing the cell. Can you suggest me for box chart as CollectionView was suggested above, any other options.